# Twig / PHP - Format string using Replace or Regex

Tags: php, regex, twig

How can I format a string in Twig as follows:

For example: `img = 05myphoto-Car.jpg`

I need to remove the numeric prefix and `-` 
I am mainly using this to output captions for images based on their filename

Desired Output:

```
Myphoto Car
```

I have tried this so far, from the docs:

```
{{ img |replace({'.jpg': "", '-' : " "}) }}
```

Outputs String

```
05myphoto Car
```

I also tried  `{{ replace({'range(0, 9)': ""}) }} // for numeric prefix - did not work`

Comment: This should probably be handled in your business logic, not your template.

Comment: I agree but there isn't much logic to handle here, I am just playing around and learning.. I also would like to understand why regex is not working

Comment: because you need to add additional extension, look to my answer pls

Comment: If you're using Symfony 4, there's [a perfect doc here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html).

Answer (score 15):

Better late than never...

Just register it (for me was on `index.php`)

```
$app['twig']->addFilter('preg_replace', new Twig_Filter_Function(function ($subject, $pattern, $replacement) {
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
}));
```

Then on the view: `{{myVar|preg_replace('/\\d+/','')}}`

Notice that all backslashes MUST be escaped, if not, they will be removed by Twig...

Answer (score 4):

This works for me just fine (Craft CMS):

```
{# Removes all characters other than numbers and + #}
{{ profile.phone|replace('/[^0-9+]/', '') }}
```

Comment: That appears to be a Craft CMS-specific extension: https://craftcms.com/changelog#2-2-2579

Comment: Yes, in Twig it just returns: The "replace" filter expects an array or "Traversable" as replace values, got "string".

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to do it in the template, though it would be better as a controller/service, [you can enable the `preg_replace` filter](https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions) and strip numbers with something like `preg_replace('/\d+/','')` and use the capitalize filter in addition.

Comment: So there isn't a built-in regex extension, either I have to extend Twig myself or use a third party filter?

Comment: as I know currenly Twig uses regexp only for comparisons http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Anderson Ivan Witzke's answer is good, but outdated. Here is an update for 2023.

In the file where you set up your template environment, add this:

```
$twig->addFilter(
  new \Twig\TwigFilter('regexReplace', function ($string, $pattern, $replacement) {
  return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}));
```

Other than that, you can follow his answer: use it with `{{myVar|preg_replace('/\\d+/','')}}` (making sure to escape each backslash with an additional backslash).