# preg_replace in Twig filter won't accept string as RegEx

Tags: php, regex, symfony, twig, preg-replace

I have a very simple filter in Twig in a Symfony 4.3 project that wraps PHP's `preg_replace` function. I want to use it, to get rid of newslines, tabs, multiple whitespaces etc. but I also want to use it for other tasks later.

I came up with this filter:

```
class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('preg_replace', [$this, 'preg_replace']),
        ];
    }

    public function preg_replace(string $subject, string $pattern, string $replacement): string
    {
        return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
    }
}
```

Unfortunalety the string is never updated, when I call it like this:

```
{{ value|preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ') %}
```

However, it does work when I insert the RegEx directly into the function like:

```
return preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $subject);
```

I also removed the type hint `string`, in case a RegEx does have another internal type, but without any luck.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Hve you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/48026470/2776343 ? (Notice that all backslashes MUST be escaped, if not, they will be removed by Twig)

Comment: @AndreaManzi Oh boy, that solves it. Thank you.